# Doubts on npm install dependency version selection

Tags: npm, npm-install

I try to install `firebase-admin@4.0.6` with `npm install firebase-admin@4.0.6`, and I got this dependency tree via `npm ls`:

```
└─┬ firebase-admin@4.0.6
  ├── @types/jsonwebtoken@7.2.0 extraneous
  ├── faye-websocket@0.9.3 extraneous
  └── jsonwebtoken@7.1.9 extraneous
```

However, the depdendency range I got from `package.json` of [`firebase-admin@4.0.6`](https://registry.npmjs.org/firebase-admin/4.0.6) is:

```
dependencies: {
    @types/jsonwebtoken: "^7.1.33",
    faye-websocket: "0.9.3",
    jsonwebtoken: "7.1.9"
},
```

For [`@types/jsonwebtoken`](http://registry.npmjs.org/@types/jsonwebtoken), it has a list of versions that satisfies the range `^7.1.33`:

```
7.1.33: "2016-10-06T16:57:57.575Z",
7.2.0: "2016-12-29T23:56:39.629Z",
7.2.1: "2017-06-05T19:56:31.609Z",
7.2.2: "2017-07-07T20:53:26.913Z",
7.2.3: "2017-08-03T14:00:05.795Z",
7.2.4: "2017-12-07T21:20:47.174Z",
7.2.5: "2017-12-13T19:13:57.718Z",
7.2.6: "2018-03-16T22:11:14.916Z",
7.2.7: "2018-04-30T16:19:55.931Z",
7.2.8: "2018-07-02T20:49:13.504Z",
```

What confused me is that why when I try to install, it chooses `7.2.0` instead of the highest one `7.2.8`.
Thanks for your time!

Comment: run `npm install` and check any warning messages for versioning. It will default to a different version if you don't have the correct version installed for other packages.

Comment: I have checked the installed version in a docker container, that's a brand-new container, so the environment should be clean, and no other packages have been installed before. Besides, I have checked the installation log, and it seems there is no  warning on this package's versioning. Thanks for your kind reply!